# Distinct numbers in array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I have no idea what to do. Please help me with code or tell me what textbook to look up or something; I need code to finish this program and I would love an explanation of what I'm looking at..

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
   short num[100], size, //declare an array of type short that has 100 elements
      unique[100], number,  // declare a second array to help solve the problem; number counts the number of unique values
      k;   // loop control variable; may need other variables
   cout<<"enter the number of values to store in the array\n";
   cin>>size;
   cout<<”enter the “<<size<<” values to be used as data for this program\n”;
   for(k=0; k<size; k++)
      cin>>num[k];

   // print the contents of the array
   cout<<"\nthere are "<<size<<" values in the array\n";
   for(k=0; k<size; k++)
      cout<<num[k]<<’ ‘; // there is one space between each number in the display
   cout<<endl;  // cursor moved to next output line

   cout<<"the program will count the number of different (distinct) values found in the array\n";   

   //************************************************************
   //Put the code here that counts the number of unique values stored in the 
   //array num.  The variable number will contain the count.
   //************************************************************

   cout<<endl<<number<<" unique values were found in the "<<size<<" element array\n";
   // pause the program to see the results
   system("pause");
   //return 0;       
}
```

I have to do one of these two things and I don't know what they mean?

Algorithm – unique array is used to help find the solution, used to avoid counting any value more than one time
 Set number to 0 - this represents the number of distinct values in the data set; also used as a subscript in the unique array
 Loop from 0 to size by one, proceeding through successive elements of the data (num) array
   Store value of current array element in non-array variable (SV)
   Set event_flag to 0
   Loop from 0 to number by one, proceeding through successive elements of unique array
     If SV is equal to current element of unique array
       Set event_flag to 1
     Break (stop) inner loop
   End of inner loop
   If event_flag is equal to 0 (value not found in unique array and not previously counted)
     Store SV in element number of unique array
   Increment the value of number
 End of outer loop
 **Solution** – the variable number contains the count of distinct values in the data array

**Alternate Algorithm**
 Algorithm that does not use the event_flag (loop control variable can be used to determine if event occurred)

Algorithm – unique array is used to help find the solution, used to avoid counting any value more than one time
 Set number to 0 - this represents the number of distinct values in the data set; also used as a subscript in the unique array
 Loop from 0 to size by one, proceeding through successive elements of the data (num) array
   Store value of current array element in non-array variable (SV)
   Loop from 0 to number by one, proceeding through successive elements of unique array
     If SV is equal to current element of unique array
       Break (stop) inner loop
   End of inner loop
   If loop control variable of inner loop is equal to value of number (SV not found in unique array and not previously counted)
   Store SV in element number of unique array
   Increment the value of number
 End of outer loop
 **Solution** – the variable number contains the count of distinct values in the data array

I put this in mine:

```
//************************************************************
//Put the code here that counts the number of unique values stored in the array num. The variable number will contain the count.
for(k=0; k<size; k++)
num=SV;
event_flag=0;
for(k=1; k<number; k++)
if(SV=unique)
return true;
return false; 
//************************************************************
```

It's not working, obviously.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't use `k` twice. If you have two loops you should use different variables for each. Also it should be `if(SV==unique)` not `if(SV=unique)`. Remember for equality it's `==` in C++. Also `return` is wrong, nothing in either algorithm says you need to use `return`. But basically the problem is that your code doesn't look much like either algorithm. The algorithms have been written with such detail that they are almost code already. Just carefully translate what is there, you don't need to use much imagination, it's almost like copying.

Comment: Sort the array. Print out the ones that differ from the previous. The sort bit is done here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: This question dare not be answered by any of us. Those who do disrespect two vitals: 1st they provide you with a deviating solution, or 2nd they prevent you from actually understanding how to program. We may only give you hints to assist your learning curve... That said, `return true;` and `return false;` both end your function, which means the rest of it won't be executed. Consequentially, it is wrong at this point.

Comment: And the "different from previous" bit is here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/

Answer (score 2):

This is my code, it seems to work

```
//************************************************************
//Put the code here that counts the number of unique values 
//stored in the array num. The variable number will contain the count.

number = 0;
for (k = 0; k < size; ++k)
{
       short sv = num[k];
       short event_flag = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i)
       {
               if (sv == unique[i])
               {
                       event_flag = 1;
                       break;
               }
       }

       if (event_flag == 0)
       {
               unique[number] = sv;
               ++number;
       }
}
```

For the alternative ,

his is my code, it seems to work

```
//************************************************************
//Put the code here that counts the number of unique values 
//stored in the array num. The variable number will contain the count.

number = 0;
for (k = 0; k < size; ++k)
{
       short sv = num[k];
       int i;
       for (i = 0; i < number; ++i)
               if (sv == unique[i])
                       break;

       if (number == i)
       {
               unique[number] = sv;
               ++number;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are roughly asked to do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // This is the given array.
    int given_array[5] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 };

    // This is the array where unique values will be stored.
    int unique_array[5];

    // This index is used to keep track of the size
    // (different from capacity) of unique_array.
    int unique_index = 0;

    // This is used to determine whether we can
    // insert an element into unique_array or not.
    bool can_insert;

    // This loop traverses given_array.
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        // Initially assume that we can insert elements
        // into unique_array, unless told otherwise.
        can_insert = true;

        // This loop traverses unique_array.
        for (int j = 0; j < unique_index; ++j)
        {
            // If the element is already in unique_array,
            // then don't insert it again.
            if (unique_array[j] == given_array[i])
            {
                can_insert = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        // This is the actual inserting.
        if (can_insert)
        {
            unique_array[unique_index] = given_array[i];
            unique_index++;
        }
    }

    // Tell us how many elements are unique.
    cout << unique_index;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might do that, I might do it, but the OP has been told quite precisely to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one...

You can insert `cout` statements wherever required.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int Input[100], Unique[100], InSize, UniLength = 0;

    cin >> InSize;
    for (int ii = 0 ; ii < InSize ; ii++ ) 
    {
        cin >> Input[ii];
    }
    Unique[0] = Input[0];
    UniLength++;
    bool IsUnique;
    for ( int ii = 1 ; ii < InSize ; ii++ ) 
    {
        IsUnique=true;
        for (int jj = 0 ; jj < UniLength ; jj++ ) 
        {
            if ( Input[ii] == Unique[jj] )
            {
                IsUnique=false;
                break;
            }                     
        }                      
        if ( IsUnique )  
        {          
            Unique[UniLength] = Input[ii];
            UniLength++;
        }
    }
    cout<<"We've "<<UniLength<<" Unique elements and We're printing them"<<endl;
    for ( int jj = 0 ; jj < UniLength ; jj++ ) 
    {
        cout << Unique[jj] << " ";
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.....

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach. Hope so it will helpful.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

int main(){

    int arr[] = {3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 5, 5};
    int len = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr); // Finding length of array

    std::sort(arr, arr+len);

    int unique_elements = std::unique(arr, arr+len) - arr;

    std::cout << unique_elements << '\n'; // The output will 5

    return 0;
}
```