# distinct numbers in an array by function

Tags: c++

Program will enter N numbers and count the number of values in the array that occurred 1 time
   Functions are used in this program

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// Prototypes are placed before main
void input_data(short num[], short size);
void display_data(short num[], short size);
short frequencyOf1(short num[], short size);

int main()
{    
short num[100], size, // Declare an array of type short that has 100 elements
      number;         // Number counts the number of values that had a frequency of 1

cout<<"Enter the number of values to store in the array\n";
cin>>size;
while (size > 0)// Loop to try different data sets w/o re-executing the program
{
    input_data(num, size);   // Call statement to function to store data in array 
    display_data(num, size); // Call statement to function to print contents of array        

    cout<<"The program will count the number of values in the array that occurred 1 time\n"; 
    number = frequencyOf1(num, size);  // Call statement to function to count the number of value
                                       // That occurred 1 time; this is a value returning function          
    cout<<endl<<number<<" Values were found that occurred 1 time in the "<<size<<" element array\n";  

    cout<<"\nEnter the number of values to store in the array or 0 to terminate the program\n";
    cin>>size;
}    // End of while loop
     // Pause the program to see the results
 system("pause");
 return 0;       
}
// Function definitions are placed after main
void input_data(short num[], short size)
{
short i;
cout<<"Enter the "<<size<<" values to be used as data for this program\n";
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
   cin>>num[i];
}   

void display_data(short num[], short size)
{
short i;
cout<<"\nThere are "<<size<<" values in the array\n";
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
   cout<<num[i]<<' '; // There is one space between each number in the display
cout<<endl;           // Cursor moved to next output line 
}     
short frequencyOf1(short num[], short size)
{
// Enter code to solve the problem
// Must return a count using a 'return' statement
//?
  number=0;
  for(i=0; i<size; i++)
       {
            short sv=num[i];
            short event_flag=0;
                  for(int j=0; j<number; j++)
                      {
                        if(sv==frequencyOf1[j])
                         {
                                 event_flag=1;
                                         break;
                         }
                      }

                      if(event_flag==0)
                         {
                           frequencyOf1[number]=sv;
                           number++;
                         } 
       } 
}
```

this is another i dont understand it is asking the same thing do i use the for loop like this? or something else It doesnt work

ok i tried this now it won't work

Program will enter N numbers and count the number of values in the array that occurred 1 time
   Functions are used in this program
    */
    #include
    using namespace std;

```
// Prototypes are placed before main
void input_data(short num[], short size);
void display_data(short num[], short size);
short frequencyOf1(short num[], short size);

int main()
{    
short num[100], size, // Declare an array of type short that has 100 elements
      number;         // Number counts the number of values that had a frequency of 1

cout<<"Enter the number of values to store in the array\n";
cin>>size;
while (size > 0)// Loop to try different data sets w/o re-executing the program
{
    input_data(num, size);   // Call statement to function to store data in array 
    display_data(num, size); // Call statement to function to print contents of array        

    cout<<"The program will count the number of values in the array that occurred 1 time\n"; 
    number = frequencyOf1(num, size);  // Call statement to function to count the number of value
                                       // That occurred 1 time; this is a value returning function          
    cout<<endl<<number<<" Values were found that occurred 1 time in the "<<size<<" element array\n";  

    cout<<"\nEnter the number of values to store in the array or 0 to terminate the program\n";
    cin>>size;
}    // End of while loop
     // Pause the program to see the results
 system("pause");
 return 0;       
}
// Function definitions are placed after main
void input_data(short num[], short size)
{
short i;
cout<<"Enter the "<<size<<" values to be used as data for this program\n";
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
   cin>>num[i];
}   

void display_data(short num[], short size)
{
short i;
cout<<"\nThere are "<<size<<" values in the array\n";
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
   cout<<num[i]<<' '; // There is one space between each number in the display
cout<<endl;           // Cursor moved to next output line 
}     
short frequencyOf1(short num[], short size)
{
  bool can_insert;


  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{

    can_insert = true;


    for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
    {

        if (num[j] == number[i])
        {
            can_insert = false;
            break;
        }
    }


    if (can_insert)
    {
        num[size] = number[i];
        size++;
    }
}


cout << size;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Distinct numbers in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280433/distinct-numbers-in-array)

Comment: What do you mean by "it is asking the same thing" ?

Comment: Yes, you use a for loop (actually two for loops I think).

Comment: Yes the two loops how do i incorporate the return statement

Answer (score 0):

While we're not going to answer your homework question for you, there are a few suggestions we could offer.

You're on the right path by breaking the code down into smaller functions. input_data(), display_data(), and frequencyOf1() are all good ways to think about the tasks.

It's most important that you write simple little tests for each function to prove they do what you think they do.  I'd test each one individually, like this:

```
void test_display_data()
{    
    short num[] = {1, 3, 7, 5, 3};
    short numSize = sizeof(num);
    display_data (num, numSize );
}

int main()
{
    test_display_data();
    return 0;
}
```

just to make sure it does what you expect.  Debug each little routine individually.  As you're done testing one routine and know it works, change the call in `main()` to call your own `test_input_data()` function, then start debugging it next.